# How do I see why a Mailbox Export Request failed?

Tags: exchange, powershell, export, mailbox

I'm trying to export a bunch of mailboxes to PST files and a few of the requests terminated early in a failure.

A few 5GB+ mailboxes succeeded and a few really small ones failed, I can't see anything common among them...

Performing `get-mailboxexportrequest` just shows name/mailbox/status and status only shows `Queued`/`Completed`/`Failed`

I have tried various switches and commands but I can't seem to find any more detail than the above.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a command so I can see the failure message in detail?

Comment: You export for what reason ? I ask as is it a migration from a faulty server in example (a db corruption ?) A generic tip is to use  Add-MailboxPermission to give yourselft full admin of the mailbox, in case someone messed with the security on the mailbox's object.

Comment: @yagmoth555 - SBS 2008 network, IP blacklisted and wanted a very rapid move to Office 365. The office is full of Macs and OLM's just don't work (after trying and wasting time for ages), so, I plan on doing the long game of exporting on server to PST, delegating all accounts to myself on o365 and manually importing items. A PITA, but, can't see a better way.

Comment: Did you plan to re-use the exchange or it will dead after ? As usually an IP blacklist mean an infected computer that mass-spammed from your office. For that part you can restrict port 25 on the router. Usually unblock take around 24h after the last spam to get you unlisted.

Comment: For your actual problem, did you tried the  Add-MailboxPermission to give yourselft the full admin over the mailbox ? That error happen often when security over it are not ok.

Comment: @Yagmoth555 - the blacklist wasn't through spam, it was because it is hosted on a dsl line... It is slow, crashes often and is generally awful and there is a lot of inbound spam... It has been on the plans to move to O365 for ages and this is just the final straw! ... As for permissions, this isn't an issue... I am doing it from the server using the management console. Nearly all mailboxes exported fine, it is just 5 random ones failed with nothing in common between them.

Comment: If you issue directly an Export-Mailbox -Identity user -PSTFolderPath C:\ExchangeExport, you should be able to see an "statuscode". What it's ? If nothing work, export it from outlook directly under the useraccount in problem. (see example there; http://www.cumc.columbia.edu/it/howto/email/exp.html)

Comment: @yagmoth555 - that's the way I have been doing it so far, but, there isn't a status code... just a "in progress", "Completed" or "failed". I ideally don't want to use outlook - but, I will if I have to.

Comment: I seen a screen with all that information :( Could be a SP, or for later version of Exchange.

Comment: Suggestion: Make sure to export the users once at the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start by exporting a detail report to a text for more detail
Get-MailboxExportRequest -status failed | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics -IncludeReport | Format-List > c:\report.txt

I hope your report will shed light on details of the failure

Comment: Unfortunately, for some it didn't - rerunning the command worked... However, this did find some other issues for me!

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into a continual problem where some mailboxes were failing and a couple of online resources have suggested that an anti-virus may be at fault so, as a temporary measure, try adding your shared location to the anti-virus exclusion list so that it ignores the files in the location and won't scan/change ownership of them mid-export.